# Hadoop-2.4.1 example jar generic options error

Tags: java, generics, hadoop, jar

I am using hadoop-2.4.1 examples jar on centos6.5_x64. The job has SUCCEEDED but output has not written to hdfs.

```
/opt/hadoop-2.4.1/bin/hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples*.jar \
randomtextwriter \
-D mapred.output.compress=false \
-D mapreduce.randomtextwriter.bytespermap=107374182 \
-D mapreduce.randomtextwriter.mapsperhost=2 \
/output
```

If the job is being run without generic options parser then the output is being written to HDFS.

```
/opt/hadoop-2.4.1/bin/hadoop jar \
/opt/hadoop-2.4.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples*.jar \
randomtextwriter \
/test
```

Why can't I use generic options?

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me: `hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar randomtextwriter -D mapred.output.compress=false -D mapreduce.randomtextwriter.bytespermap=107374182 -D mapreduce.randomtextwriter.mapsperhost=2 output`

Comment: May be try specifying the full path to the mapreduce-examples*.jar.

Comment: yes, your are right. but hadoop-mapreduce-examples*.jar and hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.1.jar what is the difference?